# Calculating column when an ALIAS is involved

Tags: sql, sql-server, alias

Question:

> Write a SELECT statement that returns these column names and data from the Products table:
>
> ProductName - The ProductName column
>
> ListPrice - The ListPrice column
>
> DiscountPercent - The DiscountPercent column
>
> DiscountAmount - A column that’s calculated from the previous two columns
>
> DiscountPrice - A column that’s calculated from the previous three columns
>
> Sort the result set by DiscountPrice in descending sequence.

I have gotten to the first calculation, calculating the DiscountAmount. Now, I have to calculate the DiscountPrice by subtracting ListPrice - DiscountPercent - DiscountAmount (which is an alias).

I cannot seem to figure this out. My code so far is below:

```
SELECT ProductName, 
       ListPrice, 
       DiscountPercent, 
       ListPrice - DiscountPercent AS DiscountAmount
FROM Products;
```

Comment: The answer to your question may depend on the database engine you are using.  Ex: SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: I'm using SQL Server Management Studio, @GMastros . And thanks, zerkms, that is sort of what I was thinking...in which case I cannot completely answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways this can be done.  The common table expression (CTE method) Ex:

```
;With Data As
(
    SELECT  ProductName, 
            ListPrice, 
            DiscountPercent, 
            ListPrice - DiscountPercent AS DiscountAmount
    FROM Products
)
Select  ProductName,
        ListPrice,
        DiscountPercent,
        DiscountAmount,
        ListPrice-DiscountAmount As DiscountPrice
From    Data;
```

Personally, I don't care for this method when it's something relatively simple like this.  Instead, I usually repeat the calculation when necessary.  Like this:

```
Select  ProductName,
        ListPrice,
        DiscountPercent,
        ListPrice - DiscountPercent As DiscountAmount,
        ListPrice- (ListPrice - DiscountPercent) As DiscountPrice
From    Products;
```

By the way, I think your calculation for DiscountAmount is wrong.  Since this is a learning experience, I suggest you double check that part.  Please note that I did not correct this part of the code even though I think it is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like G.Mastros forgot to sort the result set by discount price in descending sequence. So your whole query should be

```
SELECT  ProductName,
        ListPrice,
        DiscountPercent,
        ListPrice - DiscountPercent As DiscountAmount,
        ListPrice - (ListPrice - DiscountPercent) As DiscountPrice
FROM    Products
ORDER BY DiscountPrice DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer will give you incorrect results. You can try my answer if you want -

First, create a sample table -

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products](
    [ProductName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ListPrice] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [DiscountPercent] [decimal](18, 2) NULL
) 

INSERT [dbo].[Products] ([ProductName], [ListPrice], [DiscountPercent]) VALUES (N'Bear', CAST(1100.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(10.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[Products] ([ProductName], [ListPrice], [DiscountPercent]) VALUES (N'Magazines', CAST(200.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(13.50 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[Products] ([ProductName], [ListPrice], [DiscountPercent]) VALUES (N'Mankini', CAST(25.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(45.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
```

The table you get -

```
ProductName ListPrice   DiscountPercent
Bear    1100.00 10.00
Magazines   200.00  13.50
Mankini 25.00   45.00
```

Then the query as per your needs -

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT 
[ProductName]
,[ListPrice]
,[DiscountPercent]
,CAST(([ListPrice]*[DiscountPercent]/100) as Decimal(18,2)) AS DISCOUNT_AMOUNT
,CAST(([ListPrice]*(1-[DiscountPercent]/100))as Decimal(18,2)) AS DISCOUNT_PRICE
FROM [Products]
) AS [STUFF]
ORDER BY [STUFF].DISCOUNT_PRICE DESC
```

Results with my query -

```
ProductName ListPrice   DiscountPercent DISCOUNT_AMOUNT DISCOUNT_PRICE
Bear    1100.00 10.00   110.00  990.00
Magazines   200.00  13.50   27.00   173.00
Mankini 25.00   45.00   11.25   13.75
```

Results with G Mastros query -

```
ProductName ListPrice   DiscountPercent DiscountAmount  DiscountPrice
Bear    1100.00 10.00   1090.00 10.00
Magazines   200.00  13.50   186.50  13.50
Mankini 25.00   45.00   -20.00  45.00
```

Comment: I'm disappointed that you corrected the math.  Since this is a class assignment, I thought it would be enough to mention that the math may be wrong and that it should be double checked.  Additionally, you assume facts not in evidence.  @regular_kismet never posted table structures so you don't know if DiscountPercent is an integer or a decimal.  If it's an integer, there are integer math implications to consider.

Comment: Since this is quite literally my very first assignment, I'm relatively sure the answer the professor wants is a very simple SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT ProductName, ListPrice, DiscountPercent,

ListPrice * DiscountPercent / 100 AS DiscountAmount,

ListPrice * (1 - DiscountPercent / 100) AS DiscountPrice

FROM Products

ORDER BY DiscountPrice DESC

Comment: Code-only answers aren't much useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. For Future Inquiries: The previous solutions have the DiscountAmount and the 
   DiscountPrice mixed up. It should be:
```

```
    SELECT ProductName, ListPrice, DiscountPercent,
     ListPrice - DiscountPercent AS DiscountPrice,
     ListPrice - (ListPrice - DiscountPercent) AS 
     DiscountAmount
    FROM Products
```

```
2.[1]
```

[You see the discount amount is the actual discount and the discount Price is the price one pays after discount.  This may seem inconsequential for a class, but for any business, this would be the meaning of each term.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPXws.png)